# Azure stream Analytics Query to send output to different targets

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub

We are using Azure stream analytics to read messages from IOT Hub and write to Azure data lake store. The input to the stream analytics job is in JSON format and output should be in CSV format.In stream analytics we have created multiple output data sinks which point to different directories in Azure data lake store. Based on one the fields in the input JSON string we have to convert the input to CSV and write into the respective output data sink. How do we achieve this in stream analytics query?

Answer (score 3):

The conversion of formats will be done automatically. All you need to do is define your Stream Analytics logic.

Here's a very simple query that writes data in two different Data Lake outputs, depending of the value of a variable in the JSON input.

```
SELECT * INTO datalake1 from myinput
where windspeed<10

SELECT * INTO datalake2 from myinput
where windspeed>10
```

Thanks,

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)